# Magento 2 - Invalid template file in catalog_category_view.xml

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, theme, magento2.3

I have a custom template for category page `list.phtml` in my theme. `list.phtml` was addressed in `catalog_category_view.xml` as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock remove="true"  name="category.product.addto">
            <referenceBlock
                name="category.products.list">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MYVENDOR_Theme::product/list.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

The template was working with Magento 2.1.6 version. I have updated my project from 2.1.6 to 2.3 and now I receive

`Invalid template file: 'MYVENDOR_Theme::product/list.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Catalog' block's name: 'category.products.list'`

It seems that `action method` or `action` tag itself is invalid, but I can't find the correct replacing tag for it. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
<referenceBlock remove="true"  name="category.product.addto"/>
    <block name="category.products.list" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="MYVENDOR_Theme::product/list.phtml"//>
```

Comment: Tnx, I did a minor change to your answer and it fixed my issue. Please edit your answer so that I can mark it as correct answer.
I changed the <block> line to

<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="MYVENDOR_Theme::product/list.phtml"/>

Comment: Great! modified already.